# Why are these compounds classified as metamers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

[image]
Metamers are compounds having the same molecular formula but different number of carbon atoms,  on either side of functional group. 
In the above compounds, the number of carbon atoms around the ester group are 6 on each side. 
So how exactly can we call them metamers

Comment: I feel that the link doesn't have the answer to my specific query

Comment: The answer there seems to suggest that 1. Metamerism is an outdated term 2. Metamer has multiple meanings, the one you are familiar with about the number of carbons and a more general one.

Comment: The more general one seems to be constitutional isomerism itself. If I have to precisely state the type of constitutional isomerism, what will it be then?

Comment: Kind of positional. Not to be overthink....

Comment: This question came in my exam,  shouldn't there be a fixed set of rules to eliminate vagueness